# real-time Streaming of string variables in Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-iot-hub

I'm beginner with MS Azure and Power BI. So, I took the example from microsoft (https://azure-samples.github.io/raspberry-pi-web-simulator/#Getstarted) and I configured the IoT Hub and MS stream analytics jobs in order to get a visualization of my data in Power BI. The real-time streaming works realy well.

Right now, I have implemented succesfully the Hardware and the Software in the RPi and I also added the module RFID RC522, the serial number obtained from this module was added to the streaming dataset. However, I noticed that in power BI dashboard I can see only variables which contain numbers like int, float, etc. My question if there is any possibility to stream string variables, in the Power BI dashboard or what alternatives suggest me to visualize my data from the azure analytics job.

[image]

Comment: What kind of visualization do you expect with strings? Obviously text is not useful for line/bar charts.

Comment: For example: read on/off status or rfid serial numbers "1649a259",

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to display the name of a person logged on to a machine in a card.

Answer (score 0):

I only found an *ugly* and *very complicated* workaround. I created a web site that displays the string I want to display. I added this as web content and used an Iframe to display it. Needs to be HTTPS to work. On a raspberry PI you can do that with a [python script](https://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/). Not very satisfying method though.